# Google Contacts API OAuth2.0 not working

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api

Here's a code snippet I found from the gdata sample codes. I tried incorporating this, but to no effect.

```
public ContactsExample(ContactsExampleParameters parameters) 
throws MalformedURLException, AuthenticationException {
    projection = parameters.getProjection();
    String url = parameters.getBaseUrl() + (parameters.isGroupFeed() ? "groups/" : "contacts/") + parameters.getUserName() + "/" + projection;
    feedUrl = new URL(url);
    service = new ContactsService("MYAPP");

    String userName = parameters.getUserName();
    String password = parameters.getPassword();
    if (userName == null || password == null) {
      return;
    }
    service.setUserCredentials(userName, password);
  }
```

I have these doubts:
1. Is the name specified as 'MYAPP' any random name, or does it have any significance?
2. Which is the userName and password supposed to be used here?

Comment: Not sure what example is that, but you can use the OAuth Playground to check step by step the process to call the Contacts API https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/  also here you can find the documentation to call the api from Gdata: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/index#creating_a_google_account

Comment: Yeah, I get that. I am using the gdata library for making API calls, and I am doing it with Java. I am not able to figure out how to authorize the ContactsService object (which is not given in the link that you provided)

Comment: in the section https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/index#running_the_sample_code it is mentioned that the complete example is in the link https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/contacts/ and you can download the source from https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list  you just needed to select the programming language

Comment: Yeah.. but you need to enter some credentials as input parameters for the program to execute. And I am not able to figure out what exactly those input parameters are (also, it is not documented properly over there). Hence, the issue!